# Time and timezone of events created by selection in fullcalendar change date

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm creating an event in fullcalendar (v2.8.0) using [select](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) I'm not interested in the time, but the time gets set to 18:00, the timezone gets set to GMT -6:00, and the date is set to one day less than the one chosen from the calendar gui.

I've tried each of the 'timezone' options settings: default, local,UTC, and a specific named timezone, but they don't have an effect on the date and time returned.

Is there a way to set up the fullcalendar options to select a date and have that date be returned in the object?

i.e. Selecting Saturday 3rd of Sept from the calendar GUI triggers select and reports the Friday before.

```
select: function(start, end) {
}

start: Fri Sep 02 2016 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and I found some work around.
Try this code:

```
$.each(selectedSlotsArray, function(indx, slot) {
    var start = moment((slot.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
    var end = moment((slot.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
});
```